# Can't click an element lying inside iframe inside Shadow DOM using Selenium

Tags: angular, selenium-webdriver, iframe, ui-automation, shadow-dom

I am stuck on why I cannot click any element that is located inside the iframe element which lies inside the shadow root (open). Selenium throws WebDriverException saying "unknown error: no element reference returned by script". The whole page has several shadow root elements. And I am able to interact with any element inside them (like Click, SendKeys) using Selenium. But there is this one shadow root that contains the iframe and it drives me crazy why I cannot click anything anymore.

Switching to iframe is correct, - I have a valid reference to an element I am targeting. Moreover, I can simulate a click with SendKeys(Keys.Enter) invoked on an element, it really works.
Of course, it is not an option to switch to this solution just because it works for some(!) elements. JS click with ExecuteScript() also works. That is how I am dealing with this situation right now. But I start facing this issue where I do need a real-user click, not js.

Anyway, if you have any thoughts about what I might be doing wrong, please share them with me. Below is a piece of code I am using to access that iframe and then locate other web elements within it and perform some actions on them.

`var shadowHost = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//some xpath")); // element containing shadowRoot;
var iframe = GetShadowRoot(shadowHost).FindElement(By.CssSelector("iframe"));
var drv = driver.SwitchTo().Frame(iframe);

var buttonElement = drv.FindElement(By.CssSelector("button")); // has a valid reference to an element
buttonElement.Click(); // throws exception, see above in the description

public IWebElement GetShadowRoot(IWebElement element)
{
var js = driver as IJavaScriptExecutor;
var shadowRoot = (IWebElement)js.ExecuteScript("return arguments[0].shadowRoot", element);
return shadowRoot;
}`

Comment: You don't have to share your code. A minimal reproducible example will do, it **is** rocket science (at least to me) to understand what your code does with this description.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. A few minutes

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman , I am so sorry for not getting back to you. I still haven't figured out what I am doing wrong and would really appreciate your help
I updated my post, added a piece of code on how I am accessing that iframe element, and then locate other web elements within it and perform actions on them.

Comment: I meant: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I am not sure I can do it ((
I am forbidden to share the source code (DOM)
Any chance you could help me in such a case? I can try to provide any other details if needed

Comment: Not really.. You are saying: "_I have this black box with content inside, I can not share; Can you please tell me what is going wrong inside_" Alas I have no X-Ray Web Component

Comment: I understand((
But could you please at least tell me is it some kind of tricky thing (shadowRoot containing iframe) that needs to be dealt with in some different way or there must be nothing special about it and such a case should be treated as if they(shadowRoot and iframe) were separate?
Or that totally depends on the context?

Comment: iframe and shadowRoot is no different than iframe and no shadowRoot